# 1.14 SDK and Devices.PointofService relationship?

Tags: c#-4.0, uwp

I can't find an answer to this question:
Is Windows.Devices.PointOfService API and the POS for .NET v1.14 SDK the same thing? Both contain LineDisplay.
What is the relationship between the two?

TIA
Harry

Answer (score 0):

The POS for .NET v1.14 SDK is for developing .NET application. It cannot be used in UWP app programming. The document [POS for .NET v1.14.1 SDK Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/bb429024(v=winembedded.4)) also has mentioned this point.

> POS for .NET does not provide any support for the Windows Runtime (WinRT) API.

If you're developing UWP app, you need to use [Windows.Devices.PointOfService Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.PointOfService) APIs.